# How to make a variable choose if one of the two options is not null

Tags: java

In other languages I know I can do the following. But I am having trouble in Java understanding why I cannot do this. My error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String
```

My code is:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String one = null;
        String two = "two";
        String three = one || two;

        System.out.println(three);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the ternary operator :

```
String three = (one != null) ? one : two;
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8, you could use [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
String three = Optional.ofNullable(one).orElse(two);
```

Comment: will this positively work?i should try this. @arshajii

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi Yes, it will.

Comment: Good idea. But what a mess this is from a readability point of view IMHO :) Still, +1 for this new Java 8 feature.

Comment: @peter.petrov I don't agree. Personally, I find this just as readable (if not more readable) than the ternary operator version. Thanks for the upvote though!

Comment: the thing is i am getting some exceptions. so not rating you now. :P i am figuring it out

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Java syntax does not allow this.

In Java `||` is an operator which you apply to two
boolean operands. Your operands are String objects.

To achieve what you want, you can use an `if` statement,
or the so-called conditional ternary operator `?:`.

More details here:

[if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

[conditional ternary operator ?:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

The second links also contains a description of the `||` operator.

Answer (score 1):

**You should use an if statement or  ternary operator.**